# node js 'function' is not beening exported even though it is

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, module.exports

I am writing an react-app where I need to fetch some data from another website.

`const getUserData = (id, key, access_token, getWith) => {...}`
This functions fetches the data from the external source and is exported like this:

```
module.exports = {
    getUserData,
};
```

The function is then used in another file like this:

```
import {getUserData} from '../Logic/userLogic.js'

fetchData(){
const thenFunc = (arr, userType) => {
       let newUser = userType;
       arr.forEach(element => {
           newUser = merge(newUser, element)
       })
       return newUser
   }

getUserData(this.state.user.id_, ['display_name', 'profile_image_url'],this.state.user.access_token, 'id')
.then(arr => {
     this.setState({user: thenFunc(arr, this.state.user)});
    }
}
```

If I start the react-app everything works fine but if I want to build the website I get the error:

> Attempted import error: 'getUserData' is not exported from '../Logic/userLogic.js'.

Comment: AFAIK,  `import {getUserData}` and `module.exports` is not compatible. Consider using `require` instead?

Comment: thank you that fixes the build error, but now I got the error: `"exports" is read-only` on my website for that exact function `getUserData()`

Comment: Change `userLogic.js` to use ES6 module syntax

Comment: Yes thank you!! That fixed the error.